# Visual Studio 2017 - Disable CMake for dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a Visual Studio 2017 Solution that has some header-only dependencies that are multiplatform and use CMake.

I do not need CMake at all, but I keep getting a lot of warnings and issues because Visual Studio 2017 insists on using CMake, exploring these projects, etc.

Is there a way to completely disable the CMake feature for this solution/project?

*Update:*

- I load the project as a solution not as a CMake project.
- It is a header-only library and it does not require CMake to work. It is just using it for testing and other purposes.
- I keep the dependency as a git submodule so I don't want to make changes to it. It is correctly working by adding it to the main project as an include path, etc.
- The only thing I want I want is to avoid is CMake autodiscovery in these directories because I have no use for it.

---

For instance:

- Add [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to your project as a submodule in a directory called Eigen. (This is a header-only library)
- Write some code in your solution and reference the header files (you need to add the correct include paths, etc.)
- You will see that CMake will pick Eigen (when it is not actually necessary)
- You will get warnings and Targets, etc.

Comment: If you depend on third-party libraries that use CMake for their configuration, then I'd argue that you *do* need CMake. And note that it's not VS2017 itself that insists on CMake, but rather the libraries you use.

Comment: It is a header-only library. It does not depend on CMake, it is just using it for testing, etc. I am very sure about it.

Comment: If it is a header-only library, than it can't insist on using CMake. Just put headers somewhere where they are available and add path to those to -I rules

Comment: I keep the dependency as a git submodule. It is correctly working by adding as an include path. The only thing I want I want is to avoid is CMake autodiscovery in these directories because I have no use for it.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem.  I created a solution using the Windows Console Application wizard.  I updated the project to use a include path to Eigen.  I included the file `#include "src\misc\blas.h"` and it doesn't run CMake or anything.  It's just your run of the mill Visual Studio project.  Opening any of the files in the Eigen folder doesn't not cause CMake to run either.

Comment: @Fred mmm,Interesting... I will look a bit deeper. Thanks for looking at it. I actually have a much more complex project.. Maybe there is something more going on.

Comment: If you are using a solution that was generated by CMake, then it includes rules to update and rebuild CMake dependencies. You'd have to manually remove those CMake rules or create a new solution file from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't open the CMakeLists.txt with `File->Open->CMake`.  Choose `File->Open->File`.  You can also try to uninstall the `visual studio c++ tools for cmake` portion of Visual Studio 2017 via the installation tool.

Comment: Uninstalling is too harsh. This is only happening in this solution. I actually like CMake, I just dont want it here.

Comment: I do to but I don't use the bundled version with Visual Studio.  What seems to be happening is that you are using the integrated CMake project explorer that is opening it as a CMake project.

Answer (score 1):

In Solution Explorer, locate CMakeLists.txt, right-click it.
Select Custom Build Tool->General.
Erase everything from there. Make sure you have a backup just in case ...

Comment: This option does not exist.